# Where can I get the file name and line number of a node warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get these cryptic lines here:

> DEBUG: Mongoose connected (node:5983)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>   (node:5983) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How can I get useful debugging information so I don't have to guess where the exact issue is?

I believe it is somewhere in this file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const helper = require('../config/helper');
const schema = require('./Schemas')

mongoose.connect(helper.getMongoose()).then(
  () => { 
    console.log('DEBUG: Mongoose connected')
    mongooseConnected();
  },
  (err) => { 
    console.log('DEBUG: Mongoose did not connect')
  }
);

function mongooseConnected () {
    makeSchema( schema.User, 
            { id_google: '1',
              type: 'person',
              timestamp: Date.now()
            });
}

function makeSchema (Schema, dataObj) {
  const Class = mongoose.model('Class', Schema);
  const Instance = new Class(dataObj);
  Instance.save((err, results)=>{
    if (err) { 
      return console.error(err);
    }
  }).then(() => { 
    console.log('Saved Successfully')
  });
}
```

Comment: wrap it with `try/catch`

Comment: Don't pass a callback to mongoos methods when you want to use promises.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are providing a callback to your save function, this way mongoose will not return a Promise:

```
  Instance.save((err, results)=>{
    if (err) { 
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Saved Successfully')
  })
```

If you still want to use Promise then you don't have to pass a callback function:

```
  Instance.save().then(() => { 
    console.log('Saved Successfully')
  }).catch(err => {
    return console.error(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general an unhandled Promise rejection means that you're missing a catch method to deal with the error. Simply including `.then()` after returning a promise only deals with the code if it runs successfully, whereas including a `.catch` block will skip `.then` and only run `.catch`, with the error as a callback when an error occurs while executing the code which returns the promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

```
myModel.save()
    .then(() => {
    console.log('Saved');
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
}
```